# PowerShell > Get-ChildItem > MissingArgument | Total noob

Tags: powershell

I am messing around with PowerShell as per the prework of a remote boot camp I am about to start.

When running ls -l command, I get an error message (below). The support staff doesn't seem to know what's causing this. I've tried googling, but I'm a total noob and cannot find a clear response. Could someone help a fellow out? If possible, in plain English please XD.

> ls -l
> Get-ChildItem : Missing an argument for parameter 'LiteralPath'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String[]' and try
> again.
> At line:1 char:4

- ls -l
- ~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Answer (score 2):

Use: `alias ls`

to find out that `ls` is an alias of `Get-ChildItem`.

And `help Get-ChildItem` does not show that the option `-l` is valid.

The error `Missing an argument for parameter 'LiteralPath'` is because Powershell uses the `-LiteralPath` because that option is matching the `-l`, but it needs a parameter.